# tailwindcss not working on laravel. show just HTML

Tags: php, laravel, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

Hello Iused to use tailwind but suddonly stopped tailwind.
Please Help me

I tried re installing and rebuilding but not fix
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite
using laravel 10.22.0 install from here

```
Index!!!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ブログ</title>
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <p class="text-3xl bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500 font-bold underline">Hello world</p>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="container mx-auto mt-10 p-5">
            <form action="/posts" method="post" class="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">
                @csrf
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" for="title">
                        タイトル
                    </label>
                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="タイトル">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-6">
                    <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" for="content">
                        コンテンツ
                    </label>
                    <textarea class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline h-56" id="content" name="content" placeholder="今日の出来事"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" type="submit">
                        投稿
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="h-full flex justify-center items-center bg-main">テストテキスト</div>





    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

reinstall and rebuild but not fix

Comment: Do you mind stating the content of your taiwind.config.js and the relative path to this particular blade file?

Comment: Laravel 10 already has tailwind though. Instead of manually installing the tailwind, I suggest you install the package breeze based on this docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze-installation

Comment: With breeze, you have an option to install this in (blade, react, vue) + authentication (login, register, etc).